# Filter JS multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter

I am attempting to filter some events and their corresponding time slots. The data structure is like so:

```
var items = [
  {
    title: 'Category Title',
    events: [
      {
        title : '1:00pm',
        category : 1
      },
      {
        title: '2:00pm',
        category : 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Category Title 2',
    events: [
      {
        title : '3:00pm',
        category : 1
      },
      {
        title: '4:00pm',
        category : 2
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I am wanting to filter events by their category. I've tried using filters/maps but can't seem to figure it out. For example, how would I filter the list to only return items with the category of 1?

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.some()` to search for a matching category.

Comment: There are also useful functions in underscore.js and lodash.

Comment: Do you want to filter the array `events` or the parent array `items` which array events contain `category === 1`?

Comment: @Ele I am trying to return all of the events and their parent title where the individual event categories === 1.

Comment: Can you post the desired output?

Comment: hey grant check out my second implementation its pretty cool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `filter` along with the function `some` to get those items with a specific category within the array `events`.

*This example has an item which events array contains a `category === 3`*

```js
var items = [  {    title: 'Category Title',    events: [      {        title : '1:00pm',        category : 1      },      {        title: '2:00pm',        category : 2      }    ]  },  {    title: 'Category Title 2',    events: [      {        title : '3:00pm',        category : 1      },      {        title: '4:00pm',        category : 2      }    ]  },  {    title: 'Category Title 3',    events: [      {        title : '3:00pm',        category : 1      },      {        title: '4:00pm',        category : 3      }    ]  }],
    cat = 3,
    result = items.filter(o => o.events.some(({category}) => cat === category));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you need to get only the events with `category === 3` use the function `reduce`:

```js
var items = [  {    title: 'Category Title',    events: [      {        title : '1:00pm',        category : 1      },      {        title: '2:00pm',        category : 2      }    ]  },  {    title: 'Category Title 2',    events: [      {        title : '3:00pm',        category : 1      },      {        title: '4:00pm',        category : 2      }    ]  },  {    title: 'Category Title 3',    events: [      {        title : '3:00pm',        category : 1      },      {        title: '4:00pm',        category : 3      }    ]  }],
    cat = 3,
    result = items.reduce((a/*Accumulator*/, o/*Current object in array*/) => { 
      // 1. We get the events with a specific category  (In this case -> 3)
      var filtered = o.events.filter(({category}) => cat === category);
      
      // 2. If the previous filter returns at least one event, we need to push
      //    the current object 'o' with the filtered events.
      if (filtered.length) { // if length !== 0 we need to push the object.
        // 3. We use Object.assign to avoid any mutation over the original object.
        //    So, basically we create a new object with the original properties
        //    and finally we assign the filtered events to the property events.
        a.push(Object.assign({}, o, {events: filtered}));
      }
      
      return a;
    }, []/*Initial value (this array will contain the filtered objects)*/);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction. Now, I am wondering if there is a way to only return the actual event items that have a category of 3. Right now, it returns the parent and all of its children if there is a match. Should I filter it again?

Comment: @GrantVinson do you want the same output with the array events with only categories === 3? for example: `[
  {
    "title": "Category Title 3",
    "events": [
      {
        "title": "4:00pm",
        "category": 3
      }
    ]
  }
]`

Comment: Yea, I am just wanting to pull back the parent and only its children who have the category of 3. Thanks so much for helping.

Comment: You are a true hero. Thanks for helping. I've been able to chain multiple filters together now for a more robust filter for a list of event categories and their child events. Accepted!

Comment: Any chance you could explain a little bit on what is going on with the reduce/pushing to the 'a' array?

Comment: @GrantVinson yes, hold on!

Comment: ahh, gotcha. So, on mozilla, it says the first param for reduce is the "accumulator". In this example, is 'a' initially just an empty array because that is the 2nd param passed to the reduce function?

Comment: @GrantVinson see the updated answer with a little explanation about reduce

Answer (score 1):

you can use filter to get the reduced list but you can do this in other ways like reduce.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
>
> ```js
> var items = [
>   {
>     title: 'Category Title',
>     events: [
>       {
>         title : '1:00pm',
>         category : 1
>       },
>       {
>         title: '2:00pm',
>         category : 2
>       }
>     ]
>   },
>   {
>     title: 'Category Title 2',
>     events: [
>       {
>         title : '3:00pm',
>         category : 1
>       },
>       {
>         title: '4:00pm',
>         category : 2
>       }
>     ]
>   }
> ];
> let cat1, cat2;
> items.forEach(item => {
>   cat1 = item.events.filter(item => item.category === 1)
>   cat2 = item.events.filter(item => item.category === 2)
> })
>
>
> console.log(cat1, cat2)
> ```

Heres a bit more advanced you can give the function an array of categories you want and it will return an object with keys of all the categories and the events inside them. Hope this helps.

```js
var items = [
      {
        title: 'Category Title',
        events: [
          {
            title : '1:00pm',
            category : 1
          },
          {
            title: '2:00pm',
            category : 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: 'Category Title 2',
        events: [
          {
            title : '3:00pm',
            category : 1
          },
          {
            title: '4:00pm',
            category : 2
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
    
    function filter(cat, arr) {
      return arr.filter(i => i.category === cat);
    }
    function getCategorys(category) {
      return items.reduce((prev, curr) => {
         category.forEach(cat => {
         !prev[cat] ? prev[cat] = [] : null;
         prev[cat] = [...filter(cat, curr.events), ...prev[cat]];
         })
         return prev;
      }, {})
    }
    
    console.log(getCategorys([1,2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you should do here is to use **[`Array.filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** to filter your `items` array, based on the sub `events` array, which you can test upon with **[`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** to find those with `category===1`.

```
var filteredResults = items.filter(function(item) {
  return item.events.some(e => e.category === 1);
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var items = [{
    title: 'Category Title',
    events: [{
        title: '1:00pm',
        category: 1
      },
      {
        title: '2:00pm',
        category: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Category Title 2',
    events: [{
        title: '3:00pm',
        category: 1
      },
      {
        title: '4:00pm',
        category: 2
      }
    ]
  }
];

var result = items.filter(function(item) {
  return item.events.some(e => e.category === 1);
});


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following functions to get desired result:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
function filterByCategory(items, category) {
    return items.reduce((events, i) => {
        const filteredEvents = i.events.filter(e => e.category === category);
        if (filteredEvents) {
            return events.concat(filteredEvents);
        }
        return events;
    }, []);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function hasCategory(item, cat) {
    for(e in item.events){
    if(item.events[e].category === cat) {
       return true;
     break;
    }
   }
   return false;
}

var filtered = items.filter((item) => {
    return hasCategory(item, 2);
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Thanks @SamuelLiew I don't answer very often, I'll read up better on how to better contribute.